# How to get count of/iterate through all attributes that a NSManagedObject has?

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, attributes

I have a NSManageObject set up as an Entity in Core Data. After fetching the Entity, I want to be able to pull all of the attributes and put them into an NSMutableArray to populate a UITableView with.

For Example:
**Entity:** 
Project

**Attributes:** startDate(required); finishDate(optional); projectName(required); etc....

How do I get all of these into an NSMutableArray? Or is there a better way to populate the UITableView?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get this by asking the `NSEntityDescription` for its `NSAttributeDescription` objects:

```
NSManagedObject *object = ...;
NSEntityDescription *entity = [object entity];
NSDictionary *attributes = [entity attributesByName];

NSMutableArray *values = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *attributeName in attributes) {
  id value = [object valueForKey:attributeName];
  if (value != nil) {
    [values addObject:value];
  }
}
```

Note: this only contains *attributes*, not relationships.  If you want only relationship values, you can use `-relationshipsByName`.  If you want both attributes and relationships, you can use `-propertiesByName`.

Deciding whether this is a good idea or not is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: As a side question, after your if (value != nil) statement, how would I go about checking if it is a NSDate(isKindOfClass is not working with what I have tried thus far)? Or the Integer 16 Type attributes that I have.

Comment: `if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSDate class]]) { ... }` etc.  Any of the number attributes (Integer, Double, Boolean, etc) will be boxed in `NSNumber` objects.

Comment: That's what I was missing, I was doing `[value isKindOfClass:NSDate]`. Don't know how I forgot the `[NSDate class]` piece. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Simply add a method to your entity that returns an array of non-null attributes:

```
- (NSMutableArray*)nonNullAttributes {
    NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

    //Pretend you have an attribute of startDate
    if (startDate && startDate != null) {
        [mutableArray addObject:startDate]
    }

    //Do this for all of your attributes.
    //You might want to convert the attributes to strings to allow for easy display in the tableview.

    return mutableArray;
}
```

You can add this in your NSManagedObject subclass. You can then use the count of the array to know how many rows to have.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Why even bother putting the attributes into an array? Just access them from the Entity directly when you populate the tableview.

Comment: Because the only other way I know of is to hard code cellForRowAtIndexPath: like this.... if (indexPath.row == 0 ) ((Project *) currentProject).startDate ... etc for each attribute. And that is dependent on all of the attributes (even the optional ones) not being null.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use `executeFetchRequest` to get the array?

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"Project"    
                                   inManagedObjectContext:someContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [someContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

Comment: I have the entity, I want to present all of the attributes to the end user.